# Jenkins build fails with GitLockFailedException on Windows

Tags: c++, git, jenkins

I am setting up a Jenkins' slave running Windows XP to build a `C++`-based project. Empty jobs run fine, hence I conclude that basic functionality is working. Still, when I try to add a `git` repo to clone I get an error:

```
19:50:34 Started by user a.rogozhnikov
19:50:34 Собирается удаленно на build-winxp in workspace c:\jenkins\workspace\ATM-windows
19:50:34 java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: c:\jenkins\workspace\ATM-windows at hudson.remoting.Channel@223813db:build-winxp
19:50:34    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:910)
19:50:34    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:887)
19:50:34    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.getClient(Git.java:66)
19:50:34    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:569)
19:50:34    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:561)
19:50:34    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:866)
19:50:34    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1414)
19:50:34    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:652)
19:50:34    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
19:50:34    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:561)
19:50:34    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1678)
19:50:34    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
19:50:34    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
19:50:34    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
19:50:34 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on build-winxp failed
19:50:34    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:731)
19:50:34    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:903)
19:50:34    ... 13 more
19:50:34 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/plugins/git/GitLockFailedException
19:50:34    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git$1.invoke(Git.java:63)
19:50:34    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git$1.invoke(Git.java:54)
19:50:34    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2461)
19:50:34    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
19:50:34    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
19:50:34    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
19:50:34    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
19:50:34    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
19:50:34    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
19:50:34    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
19:50:34    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
19:50:34    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
19:50:34 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.plugins.git.GitLockFailedException
19:50:34    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1365)
19:50:34    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1315)
19:50:34    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1068)
19:50:34    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
19:50:34    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch4(RemoteClassLoader.java:742)
19:50:34    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch3(RemoteClassLoader.java:784)
19:50:34    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
19:50:34    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
19:50:34    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
19:50:34    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:299)
19:50:34    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
19:50:34    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
19:50:34    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
19:50:34    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
19:50:34    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
19:50:34    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
19:50:34    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
19:50:34 Finished: FAILURE
```

Searching for `GitLockFailedException` gives no clue and I think I'm missing something.
I tried to run Jenkins Slave Service as regular user (didn't help), tried to manually `git clone` in the `Run Windows Command` build step (works, though requires more effort).
What can be the problem?

Comment: probably permissions - Hudson usually runs as the SYSTEM user in services control panel, so it won't necessarily have the right access to the remote repo. Try running it as your own user to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you must update your Jenkins to the latest version. Very likely it will resolve the issue.

And do not forget to override git settings for Windows node in *Configure->Node Properties->Tool Locations*.

Comment: Updating Jenkins from 1.544 up to 1.547 resolved the problem, thanks!